# Is there an Evernote client for Linux?

Tags: evernote, linux

Outside of the web interface for evernote, is there a way for linux users to access the information in their evernote accounts? A better way to ask this might be: Is there an Evernote client that will work on Ubuntu? That may have been developed by a third party? From what I understand Evernote does not support linux users at the moment.

If you do a quick google search you will probably come up with this link about replacing that functionality with other tools, which is not what I am looking to do. I am extremely happy with this product and don't wish to change. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/322137-finding-evernote-replacements-for-linux

I'm also not looking to do battle with wine; I would definitely choose the web interface over that.

I realize this is a very specific request and I'm probably sol, but there's never harm in asking, right?

Answer (score 2):

Currently , there is no Evernote native app for Linux , but i saw an article states that Evernote 4 for Windows runs perfectly under Wine .

Source :[Web Upd8 - Install Evernote 4 under Wine](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/you-can-finally-install-evernote-4-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Nevernote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) is about as close as you'll get, I fear. I'd have to dig around a bit but I'm pretty sure I've seen a quote from Evernote folk saying *they*'d never be doing a *nix port. They're counting on folks to use the API for other platforms.